# sql count results query with joins perfomance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join, count

I have the following tables (example)

```
t1 (20.000 rows, 60 columns, primary key t1_id)
t2 (40.000 rows, 8 columns, primary key t2_id)
t3 (50.000 rows, 3 columns, primary key t3_id)
t4 (30.000 rows, 4 columns, primary key t4_id)
```

sql query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM (t1)
JOIN t2 ON t1.t2_id = t2.t2_id
JOIN t3 ON t2.t3_id = t3.t3_id
JOIN t4 ON t3.t4_id = t4.t4_id
```

I have created indexes on columns that affect the join (e.g on `t1.t2_id`) and foreign keys where necessary. The query is slow (600 ms) and if I put where clauses (e.g. `WHERE t1.column10 = 1`, where `column10` doesn't have index), the query becomes much slower. The queries I do with `select (*)` and `LIMIT` are fast, and I can't understand count behaviour. Any solution?

**EDIT:** EXPLAIN SQL ADDED

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref  rows   Extra
1   SIMPLE          t4      index   PRIMARY     user_id     4           NULL  5259  Using index
1   SIMPLE          t2      ref     PRIMARY,t4_id   t4_id   4        t4.t4_id   1   Using index
1   SIMPLE          t1      ref     t2_id         t2_id     4        t2.t2_id   1   Using index
1   SIMPLE          t3      ref     PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4        t2.t2_id   1   Using index
```

where user_id is a column of t4 table

**EDIT:** I changed from innodb to myisam and i had a speed increase, especially if i put where clauses. But i h still have times (100-150 ms) The reason i want count in my application, is to the the user who is processing a search form, the number of results he is expecting with ajax. May be there is a better solution in this, for example creating a temporary table, that is updated every one hour?

Comment: Please, use MySQL command `EXPLAIN` for your query and let us know the results.

Comment: For the sake of performance some compromises are allowed - like denormalisation. What you can do for example is keeping the number of detail rows within each master row. So if your tables build a 4 level tree, each node keeps number of its children on every level. I makes updates harder (you can use some stored procedure), but counting works with querying one table.

Comment: It would be much easier if you placed a sample of you database on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Regarding the `COUNT(*)` slow performance: are you using InnoDB engine? See:

- http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/12/01/count-for-innodb-tables/
- ["SELECT COUNT(*)" is slow, even with where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511820/select-count-is-slow-even-with-where-clause)

The main information seems to be: "*InnoDB uses clustered primary keys, so the primary key is stored along with the row in the data pages, not in separate index pages.*"

So, one possible solution is to create a separated index and force its usage through `USE INDEX` command in the SQL query. Look at this comment for a sample usage report:

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/12/01/count-for-innodb-tables/comment-page-1/#comment-529049

Regarding the `WHERE` issue, the query will perform better if you put the condition in the JOIN clause, like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(t1.t1_id) AS count FROM (t1)
JOIN t2 ON (t1.column10 = 1) AND (t1.t2_id = t2.t2_id)
JOIN t3 ON t2.t3_id = t3.t3_id
JOIN t4 ON t3.t4_id = t4.t4_id
```

Comment: Not true, there is a difference only for OUTER JOIN-s, for INNER ones theere is no difference. Optimizer will probably choose to first filter T1 table anyway.

Comment: i have used COUNT(t1.t1_id) and it has no difference. Putting where clauses in joins speeds up things a little bit, but the main problem remains..

Comment: Interesting resource found while researching. Worths taking a look: http://www.lullabot.com/articles/slow-queries-check-cardinality-your-mysql-indexes

Comment: Actually i changed to myisam, and optimized my queries to do only the necessary joins, each time. Now i have an average time of 100ms per count query, which still seems slow to me, for the table size. See also my edits in the post :)

Comment: i added a sample of my real database!

Answer (score 1):

The count query is simply faster because of INDEX ONLY SCAN, as stated within query plan. The query you mention consists of only indexed columns, and thats why during execution there is no need to touch physical data - all query is performed on indexes. When you put some additional clause consisting of columns that are not indexed, or indexed in a way that prevents index usage there is a need to access data stored in a heap table by physical address - which is very slow.

EDIT:
Another important thing is that, those are PKs, so they are UNIQUE. Optimizer choses to perform INDEX RANGE SCAN on the first index, and only checks if keys exist in subsequent indexes (that's why the plan states there will be only one row returned).

EDIT2:
Thx to J. Bruni, in fact that is clustered index co the above isn't the "whole truth". There is probably full scan on the first table, and three subsequent INDEX ACCESSes to confirm the FK existance.

Comment: i added a sample of my real database!

Answer (score 0):

`count` iterate over whole result set and does not depends on indexes. Use EXPLAIN ANALYSE for your query to check how it is executed.

select + limit does not iterate whole result set, hence it's faster

Comment: Not true, while counting rows DBMS can perform INDEX ONLY scan and not even touch the HEAP TABLE - in particular cases of course.

Comment: I don't clear understand how it is possible to perform index only scan to count rows in result set which is obtained by joining tables

Comment: Well, this is tricky in this particulat case. :-) Note that there are only PKs involved, so we can be sure that they are UNIQUE. All we have to do is an INDEX RANGE SCAN on first table (T4, the smallest one) and check if the key exists in subsequent indexes (just INDEX ACCESS, not even RANGE SCAN because of UNIQUENESS). That's why the plan states that only one row is returned in subsequent operations. This the power of proper indexing and well done optimizer.