# select count(*) taking considerably longer than select * for same "where" clause?

Tags: mysql

I am finding a **select count(*)** is taking considerably longer than **select *** for the queries with the same **where** clause.

The table in question has about 2.2 million records (call it **detailtable**).  It has a foreign key field linking to another table (**maintable**).

This query takes about 10-15 seconds:

```
select count(*) from detailtable where maintableid = 999
```

But this takes a second or less:

```
select * from detailtable where maintableid = 999
```

**UPDATE** - It was asked to specify the number of records involved.  It is 150.

**UPDATE 2** Here is information when the **EXPLAIN** keyword is used.

For the **SELECT COUNT(*)**, The **EXTRA** column reports:

```
Using where; Using index
```

**KEY** and **POSSIBLE KEYS** both have the foreign key constraint as their value.

For the **SELECT *** query, everything is the same except **EXTRA** just says:

```
Using Where
```

**UPDATE 3** Tried **OPTIMIZE TABLE** and it still does not make a difference.

Comment: Please consider posting the entire output of `EXPLAIN` into your question.

Comment: + the table schema + how many rows (abs value and in %) meet the given condition?

Comment: What is the number returned by the `count` query?

Comment: Do you run the queries through Workbench, PHPMyAdmin, some other tool or using command line?

Comment: The count returns 150, and the client will return all 150 of those records.  See the answer below.  Someone indicated that SELECT COUNT(*) result in full table scans.  If this is true, then this would certainly explain it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - I did.  See the UPDATE 2

Comment: @ypercube - We are running it through ODBC windows based tool.  It uses ODBC drivers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“SELECT COUNT(*)” is slow, even with where clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511820/select-count-is-slow-even-with-where-clause?rq=1)

Comment: Why are you doing COUNT(*) instead of COUNT(1)?

Comment: I think in order to solve your problem you will need to post the queries running against this table along with the explain output of each problem query. Optimizing server settings is a good start, however, individual query performance sounds like your problem now.

Comment: How consistent are these timings?  How many times have you run them?

Comment: Does adding SQL_NO_CACHE to the select * from query make any differance? eg making it slower? (select SQL_NO_CACHE * from... )

Comment: Could it be possible that when running the `SELECT *` query, the results are already in the cache? If you re-run the `SELECT COUNT(*)`, is it faster also?

Comment: @Random832 - I just tried **select count(1)** and it does the same thing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I iterated a couple times between the two queries.  And each time the **select count(*)** was slow, and the **select *** was very fast.  I would have almost expected that some sort of caching to take place on subsequent queries.  But it appears to not.

Comment: Could you try something like that `select count(1) from (select * from detail where mainid = 9999)`

Comment: May be it's the case of buffered/unbuffered queries? ODBC driver or the client using it set a relatively small buffer size and MySQL quickly fills it with first found rows and do not continue table scan until the client consumes the buffer and requests more? Did you measure only the execution of `SELECT *` or also the retrieval of all of 150 records?

Comment: Read http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/9/4/9 to see what I mean

Comment: Well what do you expect? By using `count(*)` the query is trying to "count" all of your columns which would take a lot more time than if you'd used only one column, i.e. the primary key `count(detail_id)`

Comment: What's the structure of the tables? Is 999 a valid key for maintableid (i.e. it's not being cast)? What's the cardinality of maintableid to the size of detailtable?

Answer (score 1):

For sure

```
select count(*)
```

should be faster than

```
select *
```

count(*), count(field), count(primary key), count(any) are all the same.

Your `explain` clearly stateas that the optimizer somehow uses the index for `count(*)` and not for the other making the foreign key  the main reason for the delay.

Eliminate the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select count(PRIKEYFIELD) from detailtable where maintableid = 999
```

1. count(*) will get all data from the table, then count the rows meaning it has more work to do.
2. Using the primary key field means it's using its index, and should run faster.

Comment: Even the worst query planner should treat `COUNT(column)`, `COUNT(*)`, and `COUNT(1)` identically.

Answer (score 0):

Thread Necro!

Crazy idea... In some cases, depending on the query planner and the table size, etc, etc., it is possible for using an index to actually be slower than not using one. So if you get your count without using an index, in some cases, it could actually be faster.

Try this:

```
SELECT count(*) 
  FROM detailtable 
 USING INDEX ()
 WHERE maintableid = 999
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*)
```

with that syntax alone is no problem, you can do that to any table.
The main issue on your scenario is the proper use of INDEX and applying [WHERE] clause on your search.
Try to reconfigure your index if you have the chance.

If the table is too big, yes it may take time.  Try to check MyISAM locking article.

Answer (score 0):

As the table is 2.2 million records, count can take time. As technically, MySQL should find the records and then count them. This is an extra operation that becomes significant with millions of records. The only way to make it faster is to cache the result in another table and update it behind the scenes.

Answer (score -1):

Or simply Try

```
SELECT count(1) FROM table_name WHERE _condition;

SELECT count('x') FROM table_name WHERE _condition;
```