# Mysql COUNT execution too long

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have an InnoDB table of 21.000.000 rows, and 13 columns. All queries including this table are very long ; a `SELECT` of an indexed column for example:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(id) FROM t;
1 row in set (29.86 sec)
```

I made some searches (e.g. ["SELECT COUNT(*)" is slow, even with where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511820/select-count-is-slow-even-with-where-clause)) , and all the answers from the same issue are : my table is fragmented. But when I look at the informations, it does not like to be so fragmented :

```
> SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_NAME="t" AND table_schema="s"\G;
    DATA_LENGTH: 1726447616
   INDEX_LENGTH: 3371892736
      DATA_FREE: 8388608
```

This give me (using http://meinit.nl/optimize-only-fragmented-tables-mysql method) a very low fragmentation value:

```
8388608/(1726447616+3371892736) = 0.16%
```

The only solutions I have is to:

- Run an `OPTIMIZE TABLE`, but it will lock the table, and this is not acceptable for the moment in production mode (evaluated as 5 hours of lock)
- Run `ALTER TABLE t ENGINE=InnoDB` (from https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16341/how-do-you-remove-fragmentation-from-innodb-tables ), it only lock in `read`, but not acceptable for same reasons.

Do you have any other solutions before I get the production in maintenance mode ?

Comment: You might get better answers on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you tried to use a field from your table instead of __*__. It might change something for the amount of data you have.

Comment: @A.D. I never speak about using `*` in my question. ?

Comment: I thought you were since you are mentioning a statement that includes it. My bad.