# MySQL COUNT(*) is exponentially slowing

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I have a database of observations.  Each observation contains a station identifier among other things.  In order to update our station list, I want to know which stations have observed more than 720 times in the past 30 days.  But I noticed something funny.  Just for kicks I was breaking it up by starting letter.  For example,

```
SELECT station,COUNT(station) FROM observations WHERE station > "C" AND 
station < "D" GROUP BY station HAVING COUNT(station) > 720 LIMIT 100;
```

This query took 1.51 seconds to complete, returning 100 rows.  Next I put

```
SELECT station,COUNT(station) FROM observations WHERE station > "C" AND 
station < "D" GROUP BY station HAVING COUNT(station) > 720 LIMIT 200;
```

This query took 5.58 seconds.  Okay I thought it probably shouldn't take that long, but I'll live.  Finally, I tried

```
SELECT station,COUNT(station) FROM observations WHERE station > "C" AND 
station < "D" GROUP BY station HAVING COUNT(station) > 720 LIMIT 300;
```

This took a whopping 4 minutes and 28 seconds to complete!

I wonder if anyone has a theoretical explanation as to why the counting appears to "get slower faster" as I up the limit on the query.  Also, I am not a MySQL professional, I just use it to get things into my csv files so I can go after them with C++.  Is there anything in my query itself that is causing problems here?  Or is COUNT() just slow?

Comment: Have you seen this question/answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511820/select-count-is-slow-even-with-where-clause

Comment: Have you tried running the queries seperately and checking the behaviour, i.e run one query with station and another with count(station). When you do this, better, if you also, run a count(*) too. compare the timings in all 3 cases and share here. Will isolate the problem

Comment: When I erased COUNT(station) from the query (ie between the SELECT and FROM commands) on the last thing it ran in 5.55 seconds.

Comment: possibly unrelated, but if you use limit you should define the order of rows.

Comment: please post the structure of your table and any indices on it.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...;`