# My "select count(id)" is too slow even though using LIMIT option and primary key

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table which has 15000000 rows.

When trying `select count(id) from <table_name> LIMIT 1` query, it is too slow.
Here `id` is my Primary Key.

Whereas if I try `select distinct(id) from <table_name> limit 1;` it takes only `0.01 sec`.

I am using mysql server version: 5.7.15

Engine Type: InnoDB

I am clueless why `distinct(id)` works fine where as `count(id)` doesn't.
Can anybody give any pointers what to look for cause of slowness?

I tried looking into articles with slow query even when LIMIT is used.
Then I came to know if we use primary key with it, it should resolve problem.
But using primary key for `count` didn't help me.
I was expecting `count(id)` query to take similar time as `distinct(id)` query.

Comment: You really need to view the query plan. But to think out loud for a minute, any id is a distinct id. So to get one distinct id you only need to get the first id in the table. Counting ids requires ... well, counting all of them. Limit won't matter - a count is always one record so LIMIT 1 has no bearing on that query. Maybe you mean (`select count(id) from (select id from table limit 1) t`)

Comment: The answers to ["SELECT COUNT(*)" is slow, even with where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511820/select-count-is-slow-even-with-where-clause#511963) might help.

Comment: Please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table yourtablename` and of `explain select...` for the two queries

Comment: Note that 5.7 has reached end of life and is no longer receiving security updates; consider it insecure and upgrade as soon as you can.

Comment: You have 2 completely different queries. They have nothing to do with each other (apart from using the same table). They give completely different results: one gives you any (random) existing id, one gives you the number of rows in your table. You cannot expect them to be equally fast.

Comment: Thanks for input everyone. 
I think @topsail comment makes sense to me that count() would require counting irrespective of LIMIT provided. And ysth, thanks for pointing out version support.